# Как объяснить постановку запятой перед И?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение из упражнения по заданию 20 ЕГЭ.

Расставьте все знаки препинания: укажите цифру(-ы), на месте которой(-ых) в предложении должна(-ы) стоять запятая(-ые).

***Я понимаю эти чувства у других(1) и (2) если (3) не могу одобрять их (4) то и не осуждаю их.***

Ответ
14

***Нужна ли запятая перед И (1)? Как объяснить её постановку?***

**Уточню, что именно вызывает сомнения.**

Двойной сочинительный разделительный союз ЕСЛИ НЕ..., ТО  часто используется при однородных членах (в сложном предложении тоже, кстати, нередко употребляется). В нашем примере, я думаю, он соединяет однородные сказуемые в простом предложении. Но кроме пары соединённых двойным союзом сказуемых есть ещё одно, третье, в начале предложения.

Посмотрите: ПОНИМАЮ...И ЕСЛИ НЕ МОГУ ОДОБРЯТЬ..., ТО И НЕ ОСУЖДАЮ.

Схема такая: О (?) и если О, то и О.

Очень интересно,  ставится ли запятая после первого ОЧ перед И при  таком раскладе однородных членов. Или это всё-таки сложное предложение? Я в этом пока сомневаюсь. Спасибо всем!

Answer (score 2):

(1)***Я понимаю эти чувства у других, и (2) если (я) не могу одобрить их, то и не осуждаю.***

Запятая ставится в сложном предложении перед союзом И.

Предложение следует считать **сложным** (с пропущенным подлежащим во второй части), так как второе и третье сказуемые связаны между собой **двойным союзом ЕСЛИ НЕ... ТО И.**

Такие союзы называются градационными, они возникают на основе соединительных и сопоставительных отношений.

Это тема связана с проблемой выбора **между однородными сказуемыми и сложным предложением** при грамматическом анализе.

Предложение тем ближе к сложному, чем больше расчлененность и самостоятельность сказуемых, особенно **при дифференцированных отношениях** между ними.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Но такое предложение будет **ОДНОЗНАЧНО СЛОЖНЫМ** не только по смыслу, но **и по своей структуре,** что связано с наличием **сочетания  подчинительного  и сочинительного союза.**

В этом случае нельзя  группировать однородные сказуемые по схеме 1 + 2, как, например,  в предложении: *Вода давно сбыла в Тереке и (быстро сбегала и сохла) по канавам* (Л. Т.)

Чтобы убедиться в этом, рассмотрим **более простой пример (с двойным союзом ЕСЛИ…ТО,** который легко заменяется одноместным союзом ЕСЛИ) и **способы его оформления**:

(1) *Он хорошо бегает и,  **если постарается**,  обгонит всех.*

(2) *Он хорошо бегает и  обгонит всех, **если постарается**.*  Здесь два однородных сказуемых и обособленное придаточное.

(3) *Он хорошо бегает,  **и если постарается,  то обгонит всех.*** При наличии двойного союза ЕСЛИ...ТО предложение будет **однозначно сложным.**

(4) Он **если и не** обгонит всех, **то  хотя бы** займет призовое место.  (Это пример с градационным союзом без запятой перед ***если***).

Answer (score 1):

*Я понимаю эти чувства у других, и если не могу одобрять их, то и не осуждаю их.*

Здесь союз И присоединяет (вливается в) конструкцию с составным союзом ЕСЛИ… ТО, и следовательно, запятая между И и ЕСЛИ не нужна.

> Егор привёл неожиданное для Лёвина замечание, *что когда* он жил у
>   хороших господ, *тогда* он был своими господами доволен. (По Л.
>   Толстому)

http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_188

Comment: Простите, мне интересен знак не между И и ЕСЛИ, а перед И после слова ДРУГИХ. Я уточнила суть вопроса, посмотрите, пожалуйста. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Sharon обосновала первый знак наличием двух сказуемых: очевидно, что предложение сложное.